# pycharm resolve conflicts grey out while the branch has a few commits behind master

Tags: git, pycharm, bitbucket

I am using `BitBucket` along with `PyCharm`, on the `BitBucket` UI, it shows that the branch I am working on is 2 commits behind master. But in `PyCharm`, the `Resolve Conflicts` under `VCS/Git` menu is grey out.

In `Git/Merge Changes`, there is no master branch in `Branches to merge` section.

So how can I update my branch with master and then commit or merge.

many thanks

Comment: You can use `git merge upstream/master` for your branch, resolve any `merge-conflicts` and then commit your changes.
Note: I am assuming you want to merge the changes from your upstream.

Comment: you could stash your changes `git stash`, then update your branch (merge, rebase), then add your changes `git stash pop` and finally commit them

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I had a very very similar problem. So in hope that it will help someone in the future... (maybe me if it happens again)

In Pycharm:

- Open the terminal
- Typed git status
- Looked up the files that had conflicts.
- Typed "rm " to mark it as resolved

After that, I was able to commit, push and get my self a coffee.